# How to go to an URL , search fro an specific class in the boddy and copy its "src"?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have created a cinema website  for  a school project(buy tickets, booking seats and all that). However the trailers URL's expire after 24 hours from the IMDB data base. (I'm not using You-Tube because the videos show too many ads , recommendation videos/channels, etc). So, every time i present my project I need to copy paste the new link into my JSON file.  I would like to write a method to go to the specific movies' URLs and search for the class of the video tag and copy its "src" (see pic), which will always have am updated link.

Is it possible?

[image: pic from the body with the video element]

Answer (score 0):

You can search for the `video` html tag in the html document and then get the value of `src` as following:

```
const videoNode = document.querySelector("video");
const videoSource = videoNode.src;
console.log("video source: ", videoSource);
```

If your video is embedded in an iframe element then you can use the following query:

```
const iframeNode = document.querySelector("iframe");
const videoNode = iframeNode.contentWindow.document.body.querySelector('video');
const videoSource = videoNode.src;
console.log("video source: ", videoSource);
```

PS: You can't access an  with different origin using JavaScript due to same-origin policy.

Comment: Thanks Swat. But how do use `document.querySelector("video")` in the body of an URL in the web? in this case IMDB